# HTMLUnit login to Facebook Ads Manager

Tags: java, html, facebook, htmlunit

I need a program to help me with my Campaign on Facebook. It has to Login to Facebook and go to `www.facebook.com/ads/manager/billing` and read the remaining amount of money left on account. What I was trying to do is using HTMLunit to login to facebook, then go to ads/manager/billing link and copy the whole page as text, find the Current Balance: xx.xx and display it (somewhere). Problem is when I go to ads/manager/billing, that page is loading something, and only after that it shows the full content. So my code is displaying me the text "Loading, please wait" and not the final page. Here is the code:

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_45);
    webClient.setJavaScriptEngine(new JavaScriptEngine(webClient));

    HtmlPage page1 = null;
    try {
        page1 = webClient.getPage("https://www.facebook.com");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    final HtmlForm form = (HtmlForm) page1.getElementById("login_form");

    final HtmlSubmitInput button = (HtmlSubmitInput) form.getInputsByValue("Log In").get(0);
    final HtmlTextInput textField = (HtmlTextInput) page1.getElementById("email");
    textField.setValueAttribute("asd@gmail.com");
    final HtmlPasswordInput textField2 = (HtmlPasswordInput) page1.getElementById("pass");
    textField2.setValueAttribute("mypass");
    try {
        HtmlPage page2 = button.click();
        System.out.println(page2.getTitleText());


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    HtmlPage page = null;
    try {
        page = webClient.getPage("https://www.facebook.com/ads/manager/billing");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Get page error");
    }


    System.out.println(page.asText());
```

Is there any other or easier way to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Yes...the easier and correct way to do this is using the Facebook Ads API.

Comment: Don't scrape Facebook. First of it is not allowed by Facebook Scraping Policy. Secondly it will break every day when Facebook changes something. Third just use the API.

Comment: Thanks a lot, API helped.